# adding a column in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, alter-table

Can I have one single stored procedure to add a new column to a table and work on the column afterwords? For example, I have following stored procedure:

```
...

alter table tb1
add col1 varchar(1) null

insert into tb1(col1)
values ('Y')
```

I got an error saying

> col1 is invalid.

Comment: Do you execute go command after adding the column.?

Comment: You can't have `GO` statements in the middle of a stored procedure

Comment: SQL Server is checking that the column exists when you are creating the proc, thus you'd have to manually add the column, create the proc, then remove the column to get this to work. I would suggest the dynamic SQL workaround that @LittleBobbyTables has added, though possibly using `sp_executesql` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try creating the table with a default value of 'Y' instead of inserting the values afterwards.

```
alter table tb1 add col1 varchar(1) not null DEFAULT ('Y')
```

You would need `GO` in between the two lines to have the table created, as per the `GO` documentation:

> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL Server.

However, you can't have `GO` statements in stored procedures.

**EDIT**

Alternately, you could use the `EXEC` statement to execute your code:

```
EXEC ('alter table tb1 add col1 varchar(1) null')
EXEC ('update tb1 set col1 = ''Y''')
```

Comment: I just give an example, in reality, I have many other stuff to do in the stored procedure. I just wonder if I have to alter the table outside the store procedure?

Comment: IN general it is a betterchoice to alter tables outside of a stored proc. DO you really want to add a column each time teh proc runs or only add it once? PLus you shoudl have all structure schanges saved as SQl scripts and put into source control to make it easiier to move them to prod or to recreate teh database on a anotehr server.

Comment: The `EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE ...')` statement worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this, then you don't need to worry about SQL injection:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Add_DB_Field

(@FieldName varchar(100))

AS

ALTER TABLE Readings ADD tmpCol VARCHAR(100) NULL

EXEC sp_RENAME 'Readings.tmpCol' , @FieldName, 'COLUMN'
```